# Chart Series Enabled Property has no effect

Tags: c#

I have a chart with many series. I'm trying to use the `Enabled` property to set whether a series is visible or not.

```
private void cbEnglish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QueueTimes.Series[0].Enabled = cbEnglish.Checked;
}
```

The Locales view shows that after running this code the `Enabled` property is set accordingly, yet the series is still displayed on screen?

I've tried changing the index to the series name as well. Any ideas as to why would be greatly appreciated.

---

[image][image]

Comment: give us more context. is this the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace, on a Windows Forms? the chart might need to render again.

Comment: Yes this is a Windows form. I will look into how to render the chart again. Thanks!

Comment: It ought to show right away, no need to refresh or render it (unless you also want to change data for the xxxPaint events)!.  If cbEnglish is a CheckBox: Why not use the CheckChanged event?? (Both will work, though) Is it initialized correctly? (I always forget that ;-)

Comment: _The Locales view shows_ Huh? The Local view should not anything else than this, sender and e..? Can you post an image?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll test and revert back ASAP

Comment: I've had no luck, I've edited my post with 2 screen shots. 1 screen shot is of the `Locals` after code has been executed to set `Enabled` property to true. Is there perhaps something else that could hide the series or interfere with the `Enabled` Property?